# Writing data to a database not working

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm having problem saving data to a local database on my program. It's doesn't store the value's inputted by the user in the User table. What could be the problem, some code and picture below.

---

```
public void addInformationToDatabase()
    {
        string Sex = ddlGender.Text;
        string Name = tbxName.Text;
        string DOB = tbxDOB.Text;

        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = Con;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User (Gender,Name,DOB) VALUES(@Sex,@Name,@DOB)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", Sex);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
    }

protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addInformationToDatabase();
    }
```

---

[image: ERROR]

[image: Were I want to store user information]

[image: User table]

**Any help much appreciated**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USER is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) for Sql Server. To use it you need to enclose it in square brackets

```
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [User] (Gender,Name,DOB) VALUES(@Sex,@Name,@DOB)";
```

If you are still able to change that name, I suggest to do it as soon as possible, because you will have to remember this problem every time you work with that table

Comment: Awh, my bad. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just realised. Changed it now and it's working, thanks for the help!

Comment: DOB is a date in the table, you create a parameter with AddWithValue passing a string. So, the parameter type is an NVarWChar not a Date. You could resolve with AddWithValue("@DOB", Convert.ToDateTime(DOB))